# Nvidia GTX570 driver install issues

Tags: nvidia

I'm having issues installing the NVIDIA drivers for my GTX570 in Ubuntu 13.10.
When I navigate to the additional drivers tab, it states "No additional drivers available."
This is a desktop PC, not a laptop, so I'm stumped as to why I am not seeing anything.

I've tried several different manual installs, but all have resulted in a black screen at reboot and a re-install of the OS.

Any help/tips/tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by running

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

and rebooting my pc.